# get postrgresql EXPLAIN ANALIZE as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

so if i execute an EXPLAIN ANALIZE query on postgresql i get this result:

### QUERY PLAN

```
Seq Scan on yellow_tripdata_staging (cost=0.00..3686590.00 rows=67978653 width=198) (actual time=0.009..307340.447 rows=92987719 loops=1)
Filter: ((passenger_count)::text = '1'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 38177324
Planning time: 0.306 ms
Execution time: 319613.033 ms
```

query plan being the column name and the others being the rows, is there a way to get this data with every row being a column?

something like:

filter | rows removed | planning time | execution time |

stuff | 38177324 | .0306 ms |319613.03 ms|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace function get_explain_as_json(text, out json) language plpgsql as $$
begin
  execute 'explain (analyse, verbose, format json) ' || $1 into $2;
  return;
end $$;

select
  j,
  j->0->>'Planning Time' as plan_time,
  j->0->>'Execution Time' as exec_time,
  j->0->'Plan'->>'Actual Rows' as total_rows
  -- And so on...
from get_explain_as_json('select 1 where 2 = 3') as j;
```

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│                  j                  │ plan_time │ exec_time │ total_rows │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ [                                  ↵│ 0.042     │ 0.026     │ 0          │
│   {                                ↵│           │           │            │
│     "Plan": {                      ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Node Type": "Result",       ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Parallel Aware": false,     ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Startup Cost": 0.00,        ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Total Cost": 0.01,          ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Plan Rows": 1,              ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Plan Width": 4,             ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Actual Startup Time": 0.002,↵│           │           │            │
│       "Actual Total Time": 0.002,  ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Actual Rows": 0,            ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Actual Loops": 1,           ↵│           │           │            │
│       "Output": ["1"],             ↵│           │           │            │
│       "One-Time Filter": "false"   ↵│           │           │            │
│     },                             ↵│           │           │            │
│     "Planning Time": 0.042,        ↵│           │           │            │
│     "Triggers": [                  ↵│           │           │            │
│     ],                             ↵│           │           │            │
│     "Execution Time": 0.026        ↵│           │           │            │
│   }                                ↵│           │           │            │
│ ]                                   │           │           │            │
└─────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────┘
```

Links:
[EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)
[JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

**Update**

To get the set of plans for the set of queries, one of the several possible solutions:

```
with queries(q) as (values(array[
  $$
    select 1 where 2 = 3
  $$,
  $$
    select 2 where 4 = 4
  $$
]::text[]))
select ... from queries, unnest(q) as q, get_explain_as_json(q) as j;
```

Or wrap it into the function:

```
create or replace function get_explain_as_json(text[]) returns setof json language plpgsql as $$
declare
  q text;
  j json;
begin
  for q in select unnest($1) loop
    execute 'explain (analyse, verbose, format json) ' || q into j;
    return next j;
  end loop;
  return;
end $$;

with queries(q) as (values(array[
  $$
    select 1 where 2 = 3
  $$,
  $$
    select 2 where 4 = 4
  $$
]::text[]))
select ... from queries, get_explain_as_json(q) as j;
```

Or use [`variadic`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) parameter (almost same as previous):

```
create or replace function get_explain_as_json(variadic text[]) returns setof json language plpgsql as $$
declare
  q text;
  j json;
begin
  for q in select unnest($1) loop
    execute 'explain (analyse, verbose, format json) ' || q into j;
    return next j;
  end loop;
  return;
end $$;

select ...
from get_explain_as_json($$select 1 where 2 = 3$$, $$select 2 where 4 = 4$$) as j;
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i needed, one question thou: is it possible to get the explain for multiple queries? like, multiple rows for this explain?

Comment: @FernandoCastillaOspina Do you mean something like `get_explain_as_json(query1, query2, ...)` which returns several rows, individually for each query?

Comment: in retrospective that seems really obvious, dont know how i missed that. thanks @Abelisto :)

Comment: are you sure it should work? i added another query like `get_explain_as_json('select 1 where 2 = 3;select 2 where 2= 4') as j;` but then the db showed no results

Comment: @FernandoCastillaOspina Sorry, based on your response I supposed that you find the solution by yourself. Answer updated (but not tested).